# ERROR c++ expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Tags: c++

Hi, I can't understand why my dev c++ told me that there's an error
 in: `inversi(k)`

CODE SECTION:

```
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;

      inversi(k)= 1.0 / k; //k che va da 1 a 5 in questo caso
      quadrati (k)= k*k; //k che va da 1 a 5 in questo caso
//inverse of the number
     double inversi(int k){
        return 1.0/k;  }
//square of the number    
    double quadrati (int k){
        return (double)k*k;
    }
    double funzsomma(int n,double (*f) (int k)){
        double s=0;
        int i;
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) { //sum numbers
            s= s+f(i);
            return s;
        }
    }

    int main(){  //main 

    cout <<"la somma di cinque inversi e': " <<funzsomma(5,inversi) <<endl;
    cout <<"la somma di cinque quadrati e':" <<funzsomma(3,quadrati) <<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Could someone help me to find where is the error? I can't understand. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: The SO-recommended list of books is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you comment these lines:

```
inversi(k)= 1.0 / k; //k che va da 1 a 5 in questo caso
quadrati (k)= k*k; //k che va da 1 a 5 in questo caso
```

your code should compile with a simple:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra my_file.cpp
```

Actually, you can't assign inexistent variable behind functions.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of these two lines:

```
inversi(k) = 1.0 / k;
quadrati(k) = k * k;
```

That's not how you define functions in C++. You have the correct definitions below them.

Also, comments don't start with `>`, they start with `//`. So

```
>inverse of the number
```

should be

```
// inverse of the number
```

and the same for the comment before `quadrati`.

You need to review basic syntax, I'm not sure where you got these from.